# Windows Docker Cli - The request is not supported

Tags: windows, docker, docker-cli

I'm trying to get the docker cli working on Windows. I've followed the steps from https://lippertmarkus.com/2021/09/04/containers-without-docker-desktop/, but when I execute `docker run hello-world` I get the following error message:

```
PS C:\> docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 27b5c80932aef84e743fe88bf023bd6e1cea1bbf25b0ab8875c8af701e3282b7: The request is not supported.
```

There are two errors in Event Viewer. The above and also `cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container`.

I've confirmed the docker service is running. I don't know what else to check. `--verbose` gives me nothing extra.

All suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else comes here.

Turns out I didn't have the Windows feature "Containers" enabled.